# RStudio 1.4 knitting to PDF with bash script gives error: LaTeX Error: File `framed.sty' not found

Tags: 20.10

I have installed RStudio 1.4 on my Ubuntu 20.10 machine.
I have also installed texlive:

`sudo apt-get install texlive`

I can now create PDF files with RStudio. However if I add a bash script to my RStudio RMarkdown file I get error:

```
running: bash  -c 'date
'
output file: wd1b.knit.md

! LaTeX Error: File `framed.sty' not found.

! Emergency stop.
<read *>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install single package with [this *framed.sty* file](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=framed.sty&mode=exactfilename&suite=groovy&arch=any) by:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra
```

Answer (score 0):

As root or sudo command:

```
# tlmgr update --self
# tlmgr install framed
```

By the way, if you have a lot of disk space and some time, you can install TexLive with all packages using: `# apt install texlive-full`.

Comment: Using tlgmr will add mess to the system, using deb-packages is usually safer.